# No operator "==" matches these operands. operand types are: int == type_name`

Tags: c++, function, struct, linear-search

At the "if (size == list[i])", marks with red on the "==", it says `No operator "==" matches these operands` `operand types are: int == InventoryRecord`. I do not see what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone explain to me why is that?

```
void linear_search(InventoryRecord list[], int size) {
    int i;

    cout << "\nEnter Element to Search : ";
    cin >> size;

    /* for : Check elements one by one - Linear */
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        /* If for Check element found or not */
        if (size == list[i]) {
            cout << "\nLinear Search : Element  : " << size << " : Found :  Position : " << i + 1 << ".\n";
            break;
        }
     }

    if (i == MAX_SIZE)
        cout << "\nSearch Element : " << size << "  : Not Found \n";
}
```

Comment: How can the compiler know how to compare an int and an InventoryRecord?

Comment: I'm sorry but we probably can't see what you did either, due to many missing details. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why would you even think this could work?

Comment: You try to compare `int` with `InventoryRecord`. This is hard to comment as you didn't show how `InventoryRecord` is defined. However, it seems to be incompatible to be compared with `int` (as the compiler error said).

Comment: Stop using arrays, use `std::vector` instead. Will make it even easier to use [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), like for example [`std::find` or `std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: You cannot compare an int and an InventoryRecord, this means absolutly nothing to the compiler. Provide us what is InventoryRecord or see [HERE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) how to create your own comparison operator

Comment: Psychic debugging: `InventoryRecord` has a `int size` member, OP assumed it would magically be compared

Comment: As others have said, your question is not clear, since you have not provided information about `InventoryRecord` and any operator functions that work with it.  Voting to close accordingly.   For your code to work, there will need to be a non-member function something like `bool operator==(int, const InventoryRecord &)` that is called to do your comparison.   If you (or whoever created `InventoryRecord`) have not defined such an operator, then that explains why your code is not compiling - such operators do not exist, unless specifically defined.

Answer (score 1):

In this case compiler don't know how to compare these types. You can overload operator== for InventoryRecord class.

```
bool operator==(const size_t& size) const  {
  // Compare
  // As example return m_size == size;
}
```

Comment: Not if you want an expression which compares `some_int == some_inventory`, which is what the OP is doing.   A non-member `operator==()` is needed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

list[i] is the ith item in the array of items with type InventoryRecord. It is not the size of the InventoryRecord or the size of an object that may be contained within the InventoryRecord. If InventoryRecord is a class then it may have a method or member that is accessible that returns or contains the size.

```
size == list[i].size;
```

or

```
size == list[i].size();
```

Alternatively, if InventoryRecord is a class, you could look into adding a == operator that returns the size. However, I suspect this is not what you want. The expectation would be that the == operator would compare the contents embedded in InventoryRecord and not the size of the contents.

The expectation would be that...

```
3 == list[i];
```

would test if the item embedded in the InventoryRecord was equal to 3. Not that the item embedded was of size 3.